# Android Intents in Appcelerator

Tags: android-intent, appcelerator

I've developed an app using Appcelerator's Titanium.  Within the app, the user can send an email to a designated individual.  I would like the recipient address to be auto-populated to save the user.  I'm using an Android Intent and have everything working except for the recipient address.  Subject and body text comes in fine.  Any tips on how to auto-populate the recipient and CC address?  I've included the code below.

```
email.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

 var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
      action: Ti.Android.ACTION_SEND,
      type: 'plain/text',

 });

 intent.putExtra(Ti.Android.EXTRA_SUBJECT,'The Subject');
 intent.putExtra(Ti.Android.EXTRA_EMAIL,'username@comcast.net');
 intent.putExtra(Ti.Android.EXTRA_TEXT,'Hello');
 intent.putExtra(Ti.Android.EXTRA_CC,'username@comcast.net');
 intent.addCategory(Ti.Android.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
 try {
      Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
 } catch (ex) {
      Ti.UI.createNotification({message: 'No sharing apps installed!'}).show();
 }
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you're not using the [emailDialog](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.0/index.html#!/api/Titanium.UI.EmailDialog) in the Titanium API?

Example from page:

```
var emailDialog = Ti.UI.createEmailDialog();
emailDialog.subject = "The Subject";
emailDialog.toRecipients = ['username@comcast.net'];
emailDialog.ccRecipients = ['username@comcast.net'];
emailDialog.messageBody = 'Hello';
emailDialog.open();
```

I can't seem to get the android intent method to work either.

Hope it helps.